# thumbnail images aren't aligned right

Tags: css, image

I'm stuck with this website.
At the "projects" page, the first 2 thumbnails are totally not aligned, and I just can't find the problem..
Hope someone can help me out here!
Here's the URL:

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding some thumbnails using `<div class="hidden"></div>`. Some of those `div`'s children have the `item-thumbs` class which your `main.js` script is taking into account when setting up Isotope. So Isotope is arranging the thumbnails correctly, but some are hidden, which causes the gaps. Remove those hidden `div`s.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but I need those to be hidden, since they are part of one project (and of one main thumbnail)

Any other options I could do to remove the gaps? Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just remove them from the html altogether?

Comment: Oh right, I see now, I just have to remove the classes on the hidden divs.. Seems to be working now.. Thank you man!!